# Exceeded maximum stack depth (line 48, file "Code")

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I Create new script from google sheet, but when i debug it, i get error "Exceeded maximum stack depth (line 48, file "Code")." I already set my trigger event to time-driven, but still error.

This my script :

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu("➪ Auto Dink", [
    {
      name: "Setting & Run",
      functionName: "setting_"
    }, {
      name: "Stop",
      functionName: "stop"
    } , {
      name: "Help",
      functionName: "help"
    }
  ]);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createAddonMenu() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
      .addItem('Show sidebar', 'showSidebar')
      .addToUi();
  showSidebar();
}

function showSidebar() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('howtouse')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
      .setTitle('Cara Penggunaan')
      .setWidth(300);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
      .showSidebar(html);
}


function toggleTrigger_(enableTrigger) { 
  var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();  
  for (var i = 0; i < triggers.length; i++) {
    ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
  }

  if (enableTrigger) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('dink')
    .timeBased().everyHours(1).create();
  }  
}

function dink(email, pwd, cname, ccontent) {
    var props = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties(),
        email = props.getProperty("username_t"),
        pwd = props.getProperty("password_t"),
        cname = 0,
        ccontent = 0;
    AutoDink.dink(email, pwd, cname, ccontent);
}

function getRules_() {
  return PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().getProperties();
}

function setting_() {
  var t = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("setting");
  t.rules = JSON.stringify(getRules_());

  var html = t.evaluate()
    .setWidth(560)
    .setHeight(230)
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);

  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().show(html);
}

function saveRule(json) {  
  try {
    var props = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
    props.setProperty('username_t', json.username_t);
    props.setProperty('password_t', json.password_t);
    props.setProperty('cname', 0);
    props.setProperty('ccontent', 0);
    var email = props.getProperty("username_t"),
        pwd = props.getProperty("password_t"),
        cname = props.getProperty("cname"),
        ccontent = props.getProperty("ccontent");
    var last_link = '0';
    toggleTrigger_(true);
    var status = AutoDink.dink(email, pwd, cname, ccontent, last_link);
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    if(status == "" || status == undefined){
    //ss.toast("Proses auto promosi telah dijalankan dan akan melakukan promosi setiap 1 jam sekali.");
    } else {
    ss.toast(status);
    }
    return "success";  
  } catch (f) {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    toggleTrigger_(false);
    ss.toast("Proses menyimpan setting gagal, silakan dicoba kembali.");
    Logger.log("Error: " + f.toString());
    return f.toString();
  }
  return "gagal";
}

function stop() {
  toggleTrigger_(false);
  var sheet_log = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Log'),
      tz = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("Proses auto dink telah dihentikan.");
  var newRow = [Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), tz, "dd-MMM-yy HH:mm:ss"), "Auto Dink dihentikan"];
  var newData = [newRow];
  sheet_log.insertRowBefore(2).getRange(2, 1, 1, 2).setValues(newData).setBackground("white").setFontColor("black");
  return;
}

function help() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('help')
    .setTitle("Help")
    .setWidth(560)
    .setHeight(250)
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().show(html);
}
```

Can you help me to fix this error?
Thank you

Comment: whats on line 48 in this code ?

Comment: This script `AutoDink.dink(email, pwd, cname, ccontent);` Can you help me?

Comment: `AutoDink.dink` is calling itself... again and again without any checks..resulting in the stack error. are you sure this is correct ?

Comment: Yes. I want to create automatic click free promote button in marketplace website. And the tool will automatic refresh login and click free promote button every 1 hours from url I add in the sheet.

Comment: rename `function dink()` to `function dink2()`. also update your triggers to call dink2. see if that works